# How to use synchronized in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I hope I can understandably describe the situation. 
I want to start some amount of threads and all of them will execute one synchronized method. Consider first thread checks value of a variable in this method then the lock will be released after check.Then the second thread calls the same function. But first thread will then (after some ms) modify this variable which is in another class but second thread will (maybe) check the variable before the first changed it. How can I force the second thread to wait (without sleep) till the first has finished and changed the variable before the second checks the value? Can the first send some signal like "variable changed, u can check it now"?

Now I try to write this in code: threads started all all do this run:

```
abstract class Animal {
protected House house;
    abstract boolean eating();
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(!Thread.interrupted()) {
                if(eating()) {
                   goEat();//here house.eatingRoom.count will be changed
                   Thread.sleep(1000);
                    goback();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

All of them access this method:

```
class Cat extends Animal {

@Override
   synchronized boolean eating() {
       if (house.eatingRoom.count == 0) 
           return true;//first thread release lock and 2 thread access it but the value is not changed yet
       else
           return false;
    }
}
```

And:

```
class EatingRoom {
    final Set<Animal> count = new HashSet<>();
    synchronized void add(Cat c) {
         count.add(c);
    }
}
```

to complete:

```
public class House extends Thread {

    final EatingRoom eatingRoom = new EatingRoom();
//start all threads here so run in Animal class is executed..

}
```

Comment: This code doesn't look correct. The `EatingRoom` class has a `count` member variable of type `Set<Animal>` and your `Cat` class has the following logic `if (house.eatingRoom.count == 0)`. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are describing sounds like you could benefit from the Java synchronisation primitives like `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`.

A thread that owns the lock/monitor of a given object (such as by using the  `synchronized` keyword) can call `wait` instead of looping and sleeping in a busy/wait pattern like you have in `while(!Thread.interrupted())` which may waste many CPU cycles.

Once the thread enters the wait state it will release the lock it holds, which allows another thread to acquire that same lock and potentially change some state before then notifying one or more waiting threads via notify/notifyAll.

Note that one must be careful to ensure locks are acquired and released in the same order to help avoid deadlock scenarios when more than one lock is involved. Consider also using timeouts when waiting to ensure that your thread doesn't wait indefinitely for a condition that might never arise. If there are many waiting threads when you call notify be aware that you might not know which thread will be scheduled but you can set a fairness policy to help influence this.

Depending on the structure of your code you may be able to avoid some of the lower level primitives like synchronised blocks by using some higher level APIs such as `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html` or keywords like `volatile` for variables that contain shared mutable state (like a condition you want to wait for to ensure the result of a write is observed on a subsequent read in a "happens before" relationship.

Comment: I am trying to use wait() and notify() since hours but I don't get the right result, I always get race condition, where should I use it in my code?